# Java - Best practices - How to copy many files in bulk?

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I want to copy files in bulk, what is the best practice ?
For example I have :

```
LIst<String> pathesList ...
String dist = "c:/myfolder/";
```

The simple way is to loop throw the pathesList and every path copy to destination folder.
My question is in case there are hundreds of files and every file is very big around 50-100mb. 
What can you suggest me ?
Maybe to do copy the files with multithreading ?
**The files are not in the same folder**, the destination of all files is one folder.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use Java? Would a command-line solution work?

Comment: version of java? if 7 take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html

Comment: i guess, he is asking about how to go with large list of files and not how to copy the files.

Comment: Copying files is almost certainly IO bound.  The way to make this faster is to use a disk subsystem which supports more IOPs. e.g. an SSD can support over 1000x the number of IOPS as a HDD.  This is not something you can make faster in software because it is not the bottleneck.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying files is almost certainly IO bound. The way to make this faster is to use a disk subsystem which supports more IOPs. e.g. an SSD can support over 1000x the number of IOPS as a HDD. This is not something you can make faster in software because it is not the bottleneck.

There are tricks you can do to speed up the disk access, but the OS can do most of these for you e.g. prefetching a file when reading sequentially and caching file writes rather than committing them to disk immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The NIO Transfer method is the best one for big files but it’s not the fastest for little files (< 5 MB). But the custom buffer strategy (and the NIO Buffer too) are also really fast methods to copy files.

We’ve also see that the method using the native utility tools to make the copy is faster as NIO for big files (< 1 GB) but it’s really slow for little files because of the cost of invoking an external program.

So perhaps, the best method is a method that make a custom buffer strategy on the little files and a NIO Transfer on the big ones and perhaps use the native executable on the really bigger ones. But it will be interesting to also make the tests on an other computer and operating system.

We can take several rules from this benchmark :

1. Never made a copy of file byte by byte (or char by char)
2. Prefer a buffer in your side more than in the stream to make less invocations of the read method, but don’t forget the buffer in the side of the streams
3. Pay attention to the size of the buffers
4. Don’t use char conversion if you only need to tranfer the content of a file, so don’t use Reader if you need only streams.
5. Don’t hesitate to use channels to make file transfer, it’s the fastest way to make a file transfer.
6. Consider the native executable invocation only for really bigger files.
7. The new Path method of Java 7 is really fast except for the transfer of an enormous file between two disks.

useful link : [Baptiste blog](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/file-copy-in-java-benchmark/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all files from a directory to antoher directory and you are working on Java 7, you can use java.nio.file.Files class copy() method. It uses File System providers to copy the files. So, you do not need iterate over a set of files, and the performance is high.

On the other hand, if you have to copy files one-by-one (Java 1.4+), you can use the functionality available in the package java.nio, which were designed for intensive I/O operations.

```
// Getting file channels
 FileChannel in = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
 FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(target).getChannel();

 // JavaVM does its best to do this as native I/O operations.
 in.transferTo(0, in.size(), out);

 // Closing file channels will close corresponding stream objects as well.
 out.close();
 in.close();
```

Comment: Why don't you use the try-close as long as you address java 7 features?

Comment: problem with the Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING); is  it does not copy the files. I've tested it and found it to be true. "Directories can be copied. However, files inside the directory are not copied, so the new directory is empty even when the original directory contains files."

Answer (score -3):

**Use Thread Pool:**

1. You can use Thread Pool in which you will run a fixed no. of threads to copy files.
2. Each thread will be copying a different file.
3. As soon as one thread finished with copying; next thread will come to the pool to continue   copying of next file.

*In this way performance will not degrade and you will be able to copy multiple files concurrently.*

Comment: Writing files sequentially, by a single thread, on a given disk, is usually faster than writing it concurrently, by multiple threads.

Comment: This time PCs come with many processors so concurrency is supported by the CPUs and thread pool will take advantage of that.

Comment: Read the comment of Peter Lawrey on the question. The CPU is not the limiting factor here. The limiting factor is the disk. A single thread writing bytes to a disk will be idle most of the time, waiting for the disk. Adding more threads will only make things worse, because the head of the disk will have to move constantly instead of writing in contiguous blocks.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer but I do not understand how will multiprocessing parallelize you I/O? Can I increase my network connection bandwidth by using multiple processors simulataneously? You should know this.

Comment: Yes, in case of Network it will depend on the speed and bandwidth of the network not on the processors alone. Processors will just help in utilizing the whole available capacity of the Network. Suppose you are able to use only 75% of the bandwidth with single file download then run one downloading file process it will certainly use unused bandwidth to a greater extent.

Comment: Guess what, I can load the full network capacity by a single processor alone! This is because network has its own hardware processor with buffer. While network processor is busy delivering data over the network, my single and only processor is preparing the next buffer. This is called `double buffering`. There is not much things to do when all your processing is simple copying the data, where no CPU involvement is necessary at all in the ideal. So, I do not need multiple processors to keep the network loaded. So, should I use the thread pool?

Comment: If you are right, then No, we should not. Then thread pool will work only for local machines.